# Closed form of the product of these $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a series of $2\times 2$ matrices denoted by
$$
M_j=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}+a_j\begin{pmatrix}-e^{i\theta} & e^{i\theta} \\ e^{-i\theta} & e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\theta$ is real, and $a_j$ is non-zero complex numbers. I want to find out
$$
S=\prod_j^NM_j.
$$
Is it possible to obtain the explicit expression of $S$?